# Document Preview in SharePoint online Classic Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I have a site that has SharePoint online classic search to search for documents

The results usually contains docx, pdf and other file types

I have the preview enabled in the display templates and it is currently showing the preview in a small window

But my desired result is to get something like in the image below

[image]

Is it possible to get this kind of preview in SharePoint online classic search results?

Currently when I look into what is being shown in the preview, it seems to be pulling an image

```
<div class="ms-srch-hover-wacImageContainer" style="display: block;"> 
      <img id="some_item_hoverPreview" alt="Preview of this result" 
       onload="this.parentNode.style.display='block';" 
       src="https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/searchsite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc= 
       {38dj38ck-38dl-dk39-ck39-78c061f57dcf}&amp;action=imagepreview" 
       data-themekey="#">                        
</div>
```

Is there an out of the box display template available, that we can use to get large preview of the document in search results?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, there is no out of the box display template to get large screen preview of the documents in classic search results, it is by design.

You can click the “**Zoom dialog box**” in the lower right corner to set the display ratio of the document.

[image]

[image]